# Prime objects in a tensor category

Tags: ct.category-theory

Is there a general definition of a prime object in a tensor category of some kind that captures the idea of being multiplicatively irreducible?

Examples could be prime ideals in a commutative ring, group representations that are irreducible with respect to tensor product, may be even prime knots!

Comment: You could define an object to be indecomposable if $X \cong Y \otimes Z$ implies that $Y$ or $Z$ is invertible. I'm not aware of any natural use for this definition except in situations where $\otimes$ is the coproduct.

Comment: In some contexts, you can define prime *subcategories*, where $X\otimes Y \in $ the subcategory implies that $X$ or $Y$ was. In tensor-triangulated categories for instance, this leads to the Balmer spectrum, which is the analogue in this context of the spectrum of prime ideals of a commutative ring